# CUDA Best Practice if NumberThreads times NumberBlocks is too small

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm working on a Kepler K20c GPU and am writing a Monte Carlo simulation for particle movement. Since my code is embarrassingly parallel, I want to use as many particles as I can fit into my memory.

On a Kepler K20c GPU, I'm limited to a maximum of 65535 blocks and 1024 threads per blocks. I would like to know the best practice for launching CUDA kernels, given a situation where my number of particles is larger than the maximum number of blocks times threads per blocks.

Consider therefore the simplified case where I perform vector addition `C=A+B` with number of blocks `NB` and number of threads per block `NTpB`. and let `A,B,C` be of dimension `N=k*NTpB*NB`, i.e. the number of total threads multiplied by some factor `k>1`. Now usually I would start a kernel via

```
add <<<NB,NTpB>>>(A,B,C,N)
```

where my kernel could look [as follows](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/tutorials/cuda-vector-addition/).

```
_global__ void vecAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n)
{
    // Get our global thread ID
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
 
    // Make sure we do not go out of bounds
    if (id < n)
        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
}
```

Now the problem with this code, is that I only compute `C=A+B` for the first `N` elements, but the remaining `(k-1)*N` entries of `C` remain untouched.

A solution I came up with might be to instead call

```
add <<<NB,NTpB>>>(A,B,C,N,k,NB,NTpB)
```

with

```
_global__ void vecAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n,int k,int NB, int NTpB)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){                  // this is new
       
       // Get our global thread ID
       int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x
                  +k*NB*NTpB;                     // this is new
 
       // Make sure we do not go out of bounds
       if (id < n)
           c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
    }
}
```

But here I'm not sure if this is doing the correct thing and also I assume that his is terrible in terms of efficiency as I jump around in the memory.

Are there any references dealing with this problem, or some suggestions on how to handle this in a better way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The method you've used works well. It will usually, in fact, be faster as you reduce the impact of any overheads associated with initializing/destroying threads. Incidentally, the threads per block should be **1024** maximum, not 1028, and for compute capability 3.5 (K20) you should be able to have 2^31 - 1 blocks in the x-dimension.

Comment: Of course, it should be 1024, thanks! But wouldn't a different indexing eventually be more performant?

Comment: It's hard to talk about performance in hypothetical situations. You would probably get more performance processing two elements per thread using double2s, for example, but without the full code, who can say? [This presentation](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~gerlebacher/gpus/better_performance_at_lower_occupancy_gtc2010_volkov.pdf) is dated, but may be useful. Using `const` and `__restrict__` where relevant may also help.

Answer (score 2):

As [Jez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3760791/jez) points out, GPUs with compute capability 3.0 or more are not constrained by the 65535 limit anymore. If we read [Table 12. Technical Specifications per Compute Capability](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) in "Maximum x-dimension of a grid of thread blocks" row, the limit for your card (CC 3.5) is 2^31-1.

Be aware that you should compile with `-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35` or nvcc will fall back to compile for CC 2.0 and then you code will break.

Wenever you are forced to work in a dataset larger than the usual NB*NTpB then you have to use a **"*grid-stride loop*"** presented [here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) by Mark Harris.

Here an example:

```
_global__ void vecAdd(const double __restrict__ *a, 
                      const double __restrict__ *b, 
                            double __restrict__ *c, 
                      int n)
{
    for (int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
             id < n;
             id += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {                  

           c[id] = a[id] + b[id];

    }
}
```

For 2D (or more) dimensional kernels the 65535 limitation is enough to work with the maximum dataset that fits in a GPU.